# Aplication eliminating more than one blank space, and vowels. C++ OOP

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to implement an app that establishes a receptor, emisor and message, given by the user, the method "elimnarBlc" in class Mensaje is to eliminate more than one blank spaces in a line, for example, if the message its "Hello____World" that method gotta transform it into "Hello_World".

The method "eliminarVlc" its used to eliminate al the vowels like this "Hello World" -> "Hll Wrld".

When i try to use " " to represent the blank space, it gives me an error "ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer". As seen in this image:

http://oi41.tinypic.com/sd308x.jpg

If i try to use the ACII code, (32, for blank space) it crashes.

http://oi44.tinypic.com/2m7vju0.jpg

Sometimes it throws me a windows dialogue, "Aplication mensajes.exe crashed", as you can see it stops when tries to execute the "elimarBlc" method...

Hope you can help me solving this :) Thanks

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Mensaje{
  private:
          char emisor[20], receptor[20], mensaje[100];

  public:

  Mensaje (string em, string re, string msj){
          strncpy(emisor, em.c_str(), sizeof(emisor));
          strncpy(receptor, re.c_str(), sizeof(receptor));
          strncpy(mensaje, msj.c_str(), sizeof(mensaje));
          }
  string getEmisor(){
         string em(emisor);
         return em;
         }
  string getReceptor(){
         string re(receptor);
         return re;
         }
  string getMensaje(){
         string msj(mensaje);
         return msj;
         }
  void setEmisor(string em){
       strncpy(emisor, em.c_str(), sizeof(emisor));
       }
  void setReceptor(string re){
       strncpy(receptor, re.c_str(), sizeof(receptor));
       }
  void setMensaje(string msj){
       strncpy(mensaje, msj.c_str(), sizeof(mensaje));
       }
  void muestraMensaje(){
       cout << "\nEmisor: " << emisor;
       cout << "\nReceptor: " << receptor;
       cout << "\nMensaje: " << mensaje;
       }
  void eliminarBlc(){
       for(int i=0,j=1; i<j<sizeof(mensaje); i++,j++){
               mensaje[i]=mensaje[j-1];
               if(mensaje[i]==32 && mensaje[j]==32){
                                 i--;
               }
       }
  }
  void eliminarVcl(){
       for(int i=0,j=0; i<j<sizeof(mensaje); i++, j++){
               mensaje[i]=mensaje[j];
               if(mensaje[i]==97||mensaje[i]==65||mensaje[i]==101||mensaje[i]==69||mensaje[i]==105||mensaje[i]==73||mensaje[i]==111||mensaje[i]==79||mensaje[i]==117||mensaje[i]==85){
               i--;
               }
       }
  }
 };

  int main(){

      while(1>0){
      string re;
      string em;
      string msj;

      cout << "\n+++++Realizando mensajes!++++++";
      cout << "\nIngresa el receptor: ";
      getline(cin, re);
      cout << "\nIngresa el emisor: ";
      getline(cin, em);
      cout << "\nIngresa el mensaje: ";
      getline(cin, msj);
      Mensaje Msj(em, re, msj);
      cout << "\n\nEl mensaje que ingresaste es: ";
      Msj.muestraMensaje();
      cout << "\n\nMensaje sin espacios en blanco: ";
      Msj.eliminarBlc();
      Msj.muestraMensaje();
      cout << "\nMensaje sin vocales: ";
      Msj.eliminarVcl();
      Msj.muestraMensaje();  
      getchar();
      getchar();
      }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `i<j<sizeof(mensaje)` to `j<sizeof(mensaje)`. The first version evaluates `i<j` and then compares the result, which is 0 or 1, to `sizeof(mensaje)`. Even better, exit the loop when `mensaje[j]` is `'\0'`, which marks the end of a C-style string.